# Swift: Using UIImageView to display images with URLs taken from an Array [0..4]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I have an array of 5 strings that are URLs of logos I'd like to populate a UIImageView that exists inside a TableViewCell after the URLs are retrieved from a JSON response from the server using a search function.

What I'd like to know is in your opinion is:

- The best way to take the URLs from the array [0..4] and match them to a respective cell's index path?
- How to get an UIImageView to work inside a UITableViewCell?
- If there are any (Swift) libraries that would made this process a lot easier?

Apologies if this is asking too much but there isn't much resources online currently to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend posting your current code so we can see what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for in loop on the array and then use an NSURL to get the data and put that in a UIImage.